# Excel SUMIF potential issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Link to excel doc for ref : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XO2folMWlSMVlPZnp4NWlxbXM/view?usp=sharing

Hi,

I'm trying to formulate an expense log, to keep track of expense claims I make, an explanation is below:
Sum figures in column C, if Expense Claim return date in Column F is same as date in column H row 1.

So the amount to be paid column, sums up all the amounts from column C with the same expense return date as that row?

Please feel free to message if anything is unclear.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "potential issue"? Why not just `=SUMIFS(C:C,F:F,H1)` ?

Comment: I feel like you are complicating yourself a bit... 

    `=SUMIF($F$2:$F$6;$H2;$C$2:$C$6)`

Does that do what you want?

Comment: Wow, I missed a simple issue. THank you elmer007

Comment: T_T i see......

Answer (score 0):

Already answered by  **elmer007** and **Martin**, however the same has been n marked as unanswered. Hence posting answer behalf of Martin, and which answer accepted by Adam (Q.Owner)

please find below is the exact formula for the question.

1st One bye  **elmer007**

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,F:F,H1)
```

2nd One by **Martin Router King**

```
=SUMIF($F$2:$F$6;$H2;$C$2:$C$6)
```